# JSF 2: Change rendered atribute of a component on phase listener

Tags: jsf-2, uicomponents, phaselistener

Hy guys,

In JSF 2 How can I change the rendered atribute of a h:InputText component using a PhaseListener.

Before the jsf page be rendered I have to verify all id of the h:inputtexts, and after that I will change the atribute to be rendered or not.

Am I clear?

Answer (score 1):

On GET requests, the view root is not created yet during the before phase of the render response and during the after phase it's too late because the response is already been rendered and sent to the client. The view root is however available for modification during the "pre render view" system event.

```java
public class PreRenderViewListener implements SystemEventListener {

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        UIViewRoot root = (UIViewRoot) event.getSource();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <system-event-listener>
        <system-event-listener-class>com.example.PreRenderViewListener</system-event-listener-class>
        <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent</system-event-class>
    </system-event-listener>
</application>
```

Comment: I used this solution to set the mask of all primefaces:calendar components found in a view, based on their pattern attribute and works like a charm.