# Inserting JSF-foreign attribute into JSF component by PreRenderViewListener

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf-2

I want to use a JavaScript framework (named Ideal Forms) together with JSF. This framework uses some special attributes (e.g. "`data-ideal`") unknown to JSF. These attributes are removed by JSF's rendering process.

Based on *BalusC*'s [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614508/jsf-2-change-rendered-atribute-of-a-component-on-phase-listener) (from stackoverflow) I tried to cheat these attributes into a JSF component:

```
public class PreRenderViewListener implements SystemEventListener {

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
       UIViewRoot root = (UIViewRoot) event.getSource();
       UIComponent comp = root.findComponent("myForm:myField");

       comp.getAttributes().put("style", "width: 100px;");
       comp.getAttributes().put("data-ideal", "some_content");
    }
    ...
```

The xhtml code is

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myField" ... />
</h:form>
```

The result is

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" ... >
    <input id="myForm:myField" type="text" name="myForm:myField" style="width: 100px;" />
</form>
```

As you see, the first attribute `style` (known to h:inputText) is rendered to the client, the second attribute `data-ideal` (not known to JSF at all) isn't. Any suggestions how to support jsf-foreign attributes without having to write custom components? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf will help you. Html5RenderKit in the OmniFaces project espacially looks promising: https://snapshot-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/renderkits/Html5RenderKit

Comment: Since I'm not able to update to JSF 2.2 I found this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928912/using-bootstrap-related-tags-inside-jsf2-hinputtext-component) very useful. Thx, Magnilex, you made my day!